# hot deployment of large codebase to weblogic 10.3

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x, hotdeploy, incremental-build

I have a very large code base whose build.xml consists of so many jar, some war files. One .class file may refer to more than one jar file. I manually compile the code and deploy the .ear file using Ant into weblogic 10.3 application server. But this compilation and deployment takes around 10 to 15 mins time. Is there any way to escape this part? Means, when I modify any java class from ide, it would generate a .class file in bin folder. Can I take all the modified .class files from bin folder and directly deploy them on corresponding jar files without doing server restart? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend taking Ant out of your iterative development process. Since you are already an Eclipse user, install Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse and deploy/run your app from Eclipse. OEPE will take care to do the minimal amount of work possible at deploy time for a given set of changes.